# ASP.NET Core application not logging to file when deploying via IIS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, log4net

I have an application that is built on ASP.NET Core 3.1 and includes `log4net` for logging

To achieve this I did the following

- Install NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore`
- Add `loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();` in `Startup:Configure`
- Add `log4net.config`

```
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
    <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="test.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%property{log4net:HostName}] OxygenNotifyService %level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

When I run this application from my IDE with IIS Express it works without any problem and it creates the logs, so I now wanted to deploy this application to a "real" IIS server. The application runs and does everything it needs to do, however it does not create a log file.

I even tried to set an absoloute path in the `log4net` config, to `<file value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\service\test.log" />` but still, no log files are being created.

I'm beginning to don't know what to do anymore. How can I find additional information on this? How can I solve this?

I want to do basic file logging using log4net in ASP.NET Core. In .NET Core it worked without any problems. Why doesn't it here?

Comment: is there write permission for the `service` application pool Identity ? You can enable the `stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"` in the `web.config`s `aspNetCore` element  to get the basic logging for the IIS hosted app

Comment: Hi @oleksa - How do I check this write permission for the service application pool identity?

The aspNetCore stuff is already added in the web.config, but the logs in there don't contain any needfull information

Comment: Thanks @oleksa for showing me the right direction. I added write permission to the folder where the logs should be and now it writes ti without any problems. What I'm just wondering.. there was never a log or exception about this. shouldn't this somewhere be noted?

Comment: One of the things that we should check in your App pool .NET CLR Version is set to No Manage Code. That will fix the issue if you are only using .NET Core.